# Parsing a JSON Array which has a sub-array within

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

I get JSON from an URL in the following format:

```
{
"type":"test-aggregate",
"key":["loc999",2015,4,11,0],
"aggregated":[
[3,0,0,0,0,[1,2,1,2,1,1,2],41,63,[10,20,30,40,50,60,70],[10,20,30,40,50,60,70],[10,20,30,40,50],[10,20,30,40,50],[30,40,20,10,60],[30,40,20,10,60],[["75050",111],["75071",11]],[["75071",222],["75050",22]] ],
[3,1,5,1,1,[0,1,0,0,0,0,0],49,55,[11,22,33,44,55,66,77],[11,22,33,44,55,66,77],[11,22,33,44,55],[11,22,33,44,55],[33,44,22,11,66],[33,44,22,11,66],[["75050",111],["75071",11]],[["75071",222],["75050",22]] ]
]
}
```

Please note that, I don't get the data in Key-Value pair format. I need to take the values from "aggregated" key and need to parse each row as shown below for row 1:

```
column1: 3
Column2: 0
Column3: 0
Column4: 0
Column5: 0
Column6: 1
Column7: 2
Column8: 1
Column9: 2
Column10: 1
Column11: 1
Column12: 2
and so on.
```

If you notice above, Column6 to Column12 has the values from a sub-array parsed.

Any help on how I can get this done in Java? I would help me a great extent if anyone could give me a solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Add the java tag to your question

Comment: Thanks tohava... I did that.

Comment: It's bizarre to have the data organized like that, but fairly easy to process.  Just parse it into Maps and Lists, and when walking through the "aggregated" List test each element to see what it's type is.  If it's a List then just start reading from that List (a recursive routine would be ideal for this).

Comment: what does aggregated.toString() give you?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new variable of the type `List`. There's a `List` method called `addAll()` which you can use to add all the elements of the subarray to the entire List.

You will have to go through each element of the array, and use the `addAll()` method to add everything into one list.